# Handling tokens in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I went through the Quickstart on how to upload a file to Google Drive (for Android) and everything works fine. However, it isn't clear whether I am responsible for storing tokens and handling exceptions if they expire. Does the SDK code used in the Quickstart handle this for me behind the scenes?:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

If I regularly call this code (taken from the Quickstart):

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
service = getDriveService(credential);
```

and then call some drive method, will it eventually generate an exception when the token expires or does the SDK code catch this internally and automatically attempt to retrieve a refreshed token?

To be even more specific, am I required to implement the code shown here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials

What also isn't clear to me is the difference between an access token and refresh token. Then there is "short lived" tokens and "long lived" tokens. Kind of confusing.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, when you use Google Play Services, all of the work is handled for you, including getting the token and refreshing it. This is explained in the quickstart guide that you have linked, and there is nothing more that you need to do.